# Click plus to add an app Error 500. No Apps showing up

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Today when I log in to App Store connect, there are no apps in the My Apps section. It also gives error 500. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
Thanks!
(image for reference)
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqmKq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was a temporary issue on Apple's side, and AppStoreConnect is working again now.